# Is this a bug in jquery 3.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I haven't checked the other versions of jquery.. I happened to be doing a timer and ran into this issue which I reproduced here in as minimal code as I could:

```
document.getElementById("slider").value = testnum;
```

[When you click on the slider it will go back to the original position](https://jsfiddle.net/n95ehqv9/)

```
$('#slider').attr('value', testnum);
```

[when you click on the slider it will NOT go back to the position](https://jsfiddle.net/n95ehqv9/1/)

I checked in a few browsers, I don't have IE to check..
pretty straight forward question. My project involves the max being in the billions so when someone changes the value and it doesn't start to count ever again it's annoying. I'll just use the javascript version unless I'm doing something wrong
thanks

Comment: Use `.val()` to set `value` of input element i.e. `$('#slider').val(testnum);` see https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/n95ehqv9/2/

Comment: Or use `prop` instead of `attr`. There’s a difference between attributes and properties. The vanilla JS equivalent of your jQuery code line is `document.getElementById("slider").setAttribute("value", testnum);`, not `.value`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. The `value` **attribute** is not the current value of the input, it's the *default* value of the input.* The correct way to access the current value with jQuery is with [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). (Alternately, if you like, `prop`: `$(...).prop("value");`)

* This is as distinct from the `value` *property* of the DOM element, which is its current value; the `value` *attribute* is reflected by the `defaultValue` property on the element.

For clarity:

```js
$("#the-btn").on("click", function() {
  // The jQuery wrapper for the input
  var $input = $("#the-input");
  // The DOM element
  var input = $input[0];
  console.log("$input.val(): ", $input.val());
  console.log("$input.prop('value'): ", $input.prop('value'));
  console.log("$input.attr('value'): ", $input.attr('value'));
  console.log("input.value: ", input.value);
  console.log("input.defaultValue: ", input.defaultValue);
  console.log("input.getAttribute('value'): ", input.getAttribute('value'));
});
```

```html
Type something different in the input, then click the button:
<input type="text" id="the-input" value="foo">
<input type="button" id="the-btn" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Attribute** - **parameter** with what the element was created in DOM initially (as of object parameter when you create one).

**Property** - **current** value of something associated with DOM element (as of object property).

This is not a bug.

For values use `$().val()` as this adds extra layer of compatibility and future proofness to the code.